# Timezone inconsistency in momentjs and php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, momentjs

We are having problems to get the datetime representation in php and momentjs in sync. Lets say we are having a datetime with a time zone in Moscow:

`2013-06-10T10:40:00.000+04:00`

The user should see the time in local: 2013-06-10T10:40:00. No matter if he sits in Spain or USA. Following php code would produce the proper time that we need:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-06-10T10:40:00.000+04:00');
echo $date->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

The output is:

```
10.06.2013 10:40:00
```

But if we parse the same datetime string in frontend with momentjs:

```
moment('2013-06-10T10:40:00.000+04:00').format('D.M.YYYY h:mm:ss');
```

The output is:

```
10.6.2013 8:40:00
```

The browsers time zone is Europe/Berlin (+02:00). Using utc() calculates the date the wrong way also. What we need is a local time of the place, so in case of php it is the right one. Giving a parse string to momentjs:

```
moment('2013-06-10T10:40:00.000+04:00', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").format('D.M.YYYY h:mm:ss')
```

would do the trick, so the time zone is deleted. But we actually should set the parse string globally, but how?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are affected by [moment.js issue 611](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/611) - which is actually a feature request, since JavaScript doesn't do this natively anyway.  There is a somewhat acceptable workaround in the issue comments.  Please add your own feedback there as well.  Thanks.

### UPDATE

With the release of [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) version 2.1.0, you can now do this:

```
var input = "2013-06-10T10:40:00.000+04:00";
var m = moment(input).zone(input);
var s = m.format('D.M.YYYY h:mm:ss');
```

The extra call to `.zone(input)` will extract just the offset portion (`+04:00`) from the string and set it to the zone used for formatting.  There are other options as well.  See [moment#zone](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/) in the docs.

### UPDATE #2

With the release of [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) version 2.3.0, this is now a single call:

```
var m = moment.parseZone(input);
```

Comment: Thx, i'll take a part there.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the PHP timezone to Europe/Berlin

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin")
```

Might be your PHP installation/server is using a different timezone.

Comment: The time zone is properly set. Php show also the proper time. Momentjs is the problem.